# Ubuntu 20.04 randomly freeze

Tags: 20.04, hp, freeze

Ubuntu: 20.04
Notebook: HP elitebook g7
Linux: 5.6.0-1034-oem (or 5.4.0)

Freeze happens randomly. There is no link with any action and sometimes it happens once a day, sometimes 5 times a day.

It starts 2-3 weeks ago.

Nothing works: mouse, keybord, ctrl+alt+fX, .... Only solution is to power-down the laptop.

Syslog doesn't show any error.

Please, do you hay any idea?

free -h

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       8,5Gi       1,9Gi       1,1Gi       5,0Gi       6,5Gi
Swap:         2,0Gi          0B       2,0Gi
```

sysctl vm.swappiness

```
vm.swappiness = 60
```

grep -i swap /etc/fstab

```
/swapfile      none      swap    sw      0       0
```

sudo dmidecode -s bios-version

```
S70 Ver. 01.01.06, S70 Ver. 01.03.02
```

memtest86

```
Passed on 100%
```

**Edit (1.2.2021)**

ls -al /var/crash

(one crash but its happen in previous boot and 12h ago)

```
_usr_bin_seahorse.1000.crash
```

journalctl -b -1

(last 2 seconds)

```
úno 01 18:53:08 ondra-work avahi-daemon[965]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface veth3ba8083.IPv6 with address fe80::74db:e6ff:feb4:f476.
úno 01 18:53:08 ondra-work avahi-daemon[965]: New relevant interface veth3ba8083.IPv6 for mDNS.
úno 01 18:53:08 ondra-work avahi-daemon[965]: Registering new address record for fe80::74db:e6ff:feb4:f476 on veth3ba8083.*.
úno 01 18:53:08 ondra-work kernel: veth54120d1: renamed from eth0
úno 01 18:53:08 ondra-work kernel: br-f273e5b15276: port 1(veth3ba8083) entered disabled state
úno 01 18:53:08 ondra-work systemd-udevd[17727]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
úno 01 18:53:08 ondra-work NetworkManager[974]: <info>  [1612201988.4813] manager: (veth54120d1): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/166)
úno 01 18:53:08 ondra-work avahi-daemon[965]: Interface veth3ba8083.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
úno 01 18:53:08 ondra-work avahi-daemon[965]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface veth3ba8083.IPv6 with address fe80::74db:e6ff:feb4:f476.
úno 01 18:53:08 ondra-work kernel: br-f273e5b15276: port 1(veth3ba8083) entered disabled state
úno 01 18:53:08 ondra-work kernel: device veth3ba8083 left promiscuous mode
úno 01 18:53:08 ondra-work kernel: br-f273e5b15276: port 1(veth3ba8083) entered disabled state
úno 01 18:53:08 ondra-work avahi-daemon[965]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::74db:e6ff:feb4:f476 on veth3ba8083.
úno 01 18:53:08 ondra-work systemd-udevd[17727]: veth54120d1: Failed to get link config: No such device
úno 01 18:53:08 ondra-work NetworkManager[974]: <info>  [1612201988.5099] device (veth3ba8083): released from master device br-f273e5b15276
úno 01 18:53:08 ondra-work gnome-shell[2744]: Removing a network device that was not added
úno 01 18:53:08 ondra-work gnome-shell[2744]: Removing a network device that was not added
úno 01 18:54:08 ondra-work NetworkManager[974]: <info>  [1612202048.3850] manager: (vethb4cde64): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/167)
úno 01 18:54:08 ondra-work kernel: br-f273e5b15276: port 1(vethe1b03b2) entered blocking state
úno 01 18:54:08 ondra-work kernel: br-f273e5b15276: port 1(vethe1b03b2) entered disabled state
úno 01 18:54:08 ondra-work kernel: device vethe1b03b2 entered promiscuous mode
úno 01 18:54:08 ondra-work kernel: br-f273e5b15276: port 1(vethe1b03b2) entered blocking state
úno 01 18:54:08 ondra-work kernel: br-f273e5b15276: port 1(vethe1b03b2) entered forwarding state
úno 01 18:54:08 ondra-work kernel: br-f273e5b15276: port 1(vethe1b03b2) entered disabled state
úno 01 18:54:08 ondra-work systemd-udevd[17931]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
úno 01 18:54:08 ondra-work NetworkManager[974]: <info>  [1612202048.3866] manager: (vethe1b03b2): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/168)
úno 01 18:54:08 ondra-work systemd-udevd[17931]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v245'.
úno 01 18:54:08 ondra-work systemd-udevd[17931]: vethb4cde64: Could not generate persistent MAC: No data available
úno 01 18:54:08 ondra-work systemd-udevd[17932]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
úno 01 18:54:08 ondra-work systemd-udevd[17932]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v245'.
úno 01 18:54:08 ondra-work systemd-udevd[17932]: vethe1b03b2: Could not generate persistent MAC: No data available
úno 01 18:54:08 ondra-work kernel: eth0: renamed from vethb4cde64
úno 01 18:54:08 ondra-work NetworkManager[974]: <info>  [1612202048.7133] device (vethe1b03b2): carrier: link connected
úno 01 18:54:08 ondra-work NetworkManager[974]: <info>  [1612202048.7138] device (br-f273e5b15276): carrier: link connected
úno 01 18:54:08 ondra-work kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): vethe1b03b2: link becomes ready
úno 01 18:54:08 ondra-work kernel: br-f273e5b15276: port 1(vethe1b03b2) entered blocking state
úno 01 18:54:08 ondra-work kernel: br-f273e5b15276: port 1(vethe1b03b2) entered forwarding state
úno 01 18:54:08 ondra-work gnome-shell[2744]: Removing a network device that was not added
úno 01 18:54:09 ondra-work kernel: vethb4cde64: renamed from eth0
úno 01 18:54:10 ondra-work systemd-udevd[17978]: ethtool: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
úno 01 18:54:10 ondra-work kernel: br-f273e5b15276: port 1(vethe1b03b2) entered disabled state
úno 01 18:54:10 ondra-work systemd-udevd[17978]: Using default interface naming scheme 'v245'.
úno 01 18:54:10 ondra-work kernel: br-f273e5b15276: port 1(vethe1b03b2) entered disabled state
úno 01 18:54:10 ondra-work NetworkManager[974]: <info>  [1612202050.0761] manager: (vethb4cde64): new Veth device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/169)
úno 01 18:54:10 ondra-work kernel: device vethe1b03b2 left promiscuous mode
úno 01 18:54:10 ondra-work kernel: br-f273e5b15276: port 1(vethe1b03b2) entered disabled state
úno 01 18:54:10 ondra-work systemd-udevd[17978]: vethb4cde64: Failed to get link config: No such device
úno 01 18:54:10 ondra-work NetworkManager[974]: <info>  [1612202050.1231] device (vethe1b03b2): released from master device br-f273e5b15276
úno 01 18:54:10 ondra-work gnome-shell[2744]: Removing a network device that was not added
úno 01 18:54:10 ondra-work gnome-shell[2744]: Removing a network device that was not added
```

### Edit 22-03-2021

It seems that issue was fixed in kernel 5.8

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Description edited

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with new Asus Zenbook 14, few drivers didn't work and it had few issues.
I removed it and installed Ubuntu 20.10, and it works well and smooth with no problem at all.
It could be the solution.

Comment: There are so many reasons why a system might freeze so it's rarely the case that what worked on your hardware and setup will work on another. Still, although it's a generic suggestion, upgrading to the next version can indeed solve a lot of issues like this which can be caused by buggy drivers, so I think this is just about acceptable as an answer here.

Comment: @Kangaroo Could you explain which drivers did not work and how you found them as not working. I am having similar random freeze problem on Asus laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with my Lenovo laptop caused by swap file. For some reason default size of swap was set to 1Gb. Swapping literally froze my laptop to death.

The issue was partially resolved by increasing swap file size to 8Gg - freezes started to happen more rarely. Finally resolved it by installing SSD and extending RAM to 20Gb.

Comment: *"I had the same problem..."* does not make this an answer. It should be a comment.

Answer (score 0):

**BIOS**

HP EliteBook G7

You have BIOS version S70 Ver. 01.01.06.

If you have the **HP EliteBook 850 G7** variation of this model, then there's a newer BIOS available that might fix your problem. Version 01.03.02 Rev.A, dated Nov 13, 2020, can be downloaded [here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-elitebook-850-g7-notebook-pc/33386506).

Note: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your model #.

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**SWAP**

If the BIOS doesn't resolve the problem, we'll increase your /swapfile from 2G to 4G.

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `dd` command can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 16G RAM and 4G swap
```

Confirm this /swapfile line at the end of /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines...

To edit, use `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

**Update #1:**

Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take many hours to complete.

**Update #2:**

If `memtest` runs ok, then we'll boot to a Ubuntu Live 20.10 DVD/USB and see if that works reliably.

Comment: I'll try it but how is it possible that 2 weeks before there was no problem (I should mention that before and I'll edit the post)? Also if there is no memory should "at least work something".

Comment: @OndřejMoravčík When did you update/install 20.04? What did you have before?

Comment: Its a new laptop (2-3 months). I immediate install 20.04. Problem happens only for 2-3 weeks.

Comment: @OndřejMoravčík Software Updater can install new kernels, and newer kernels really want newer BIOSs. So do try my answer, and report back.

Comment: @OndřejMoravčík Status please...

Comment: I've upgrade BIOS and increase size of the swap but ubuntu freeze 5min ago

Comment: @OndřejMoravčík Please see Updates #1 and #2 in my answer.

Comment: Test passed on 100%, I don't like second suggestion (since freeze is random) but I'll try it :)

Comment: I've created new partition and install Ubuntu 20.04. It works for 5 days but system froze again. Any more suggestion please? (maybe something I've installed or HW issue)

Comment: @OndřejMoravčík Edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash`. Then look at `journalctl -b -1 | more` and look for suspicious activity that occurred just before the freeze.

Comment: Almost 3 weeks without any problem. I've updated description. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It took me several months to solve why my older and slower Celeron computer would sometimes randomly freeze for several minutes while the hard drive light remained on. To prevent the system from freezing for long extended periods while the hard drive swaps large file chunks, manage the swap setting.

To see what value swappiness is set to...
 cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness

if it is set to the default value of 60 then...
 sudo gedit /etc/sysctl.conf

add this to end of file
 vm.swappiness=10

After a reboot it will rarely attempt a swap.
My system no-longer freezes :-)